# find a harmonic function $v$ such that $v$ takes 1 on $L_1$, $3$ on $L_2$, and equals $5$ on $L_3$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $D=\{z: \Im z>0 \text{ and } |\Re z|<\pi/2\}$ be a half strip. Let $L_1$ be the left boundary $L_1:=\{z:\Re z=-\pi/2\ \text{ and } \Im z>0 \}$ and $L_2=\{z:\Re z=\pi/2\text{ and } \Im z>0\}$, $L_3=\{z:|\Re z|<\pi/2\text{ and } \Im z=0\}$.

I want to find a harmonic function $v$ such that $v$ takes 1 on $L_1$, $3$ on $L_2$, and equals $5$ on $L_3$

Efforts:

I know real and imaginary part of analytic function is harmonic. But I am not able to use it to solve the problem.

I would be thankful if somebody can give a small hint so that I can solev the problem on my own.

Comment: If your domain were not the half-strip, but half-plane instead. And suppose that you were given some function $f$ on the boundary. Can you extend that harmonically to the entire half-plane?

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho Thanks for the response. I think some function like A Arg(z)+B should work where $A$ and $B$ can be found by applying the boundary values.

Comment: Well, on the boundary you may have some complicated function not necessarily a constant.

Comment: Actually so  far encountered the problem where function on boundary was constant.  Example: harmonic function on first quadrant which takes 1 on y axis and 0 on x axis. Answer would be $1-\frac{2}{\pi}Arg(z)$. I spent so much time on this but I am not able to solve it. Thanks.